# Unable to get alignItems to work in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I haven't had this issue in React-Native, but for some reason, I can't get `alignItems` to work in React, even after giving the container a height. What am I doing wrong here?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-sea-t802v)

Comment: If you add `height: '100vh',` to your pointer class it should work.

Comment: They are centered, but they've got default margin, try to add  ``*{margin: 0;}`` at the top of your css file.

Comment: Adding `height: '100vh'` did the trick, thanks.